# How to Install Linux Kernel 3.9 in Ubuntu

Tags: kernel

How to Install Linux Kernel 3.9 in Ubuntu

Comment: Just be careful with the install regards to architecture (32bit or 64bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux Kernel 3.9.4 Install and Removel on Linux Mint and Ubuntu

http://latestlinuxupdates.com/linux-kernel-3-9-4/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This link is dead, hence @Mitch's point.

Answer (score 5):

To install Linux Kernel 3.9.4,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove
cd /tmp
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-headers-3.9.4-030904-generic_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_i386.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-headers-3.9.4-030904_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_all.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-image-3.9.4-030904-generic_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo update-grub2
```

For 64bit, just change:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-headers-3.9.4-030904-generic_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_amd64.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-headers-3.9.4-030904_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_all.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-image-3.9.4-030904-generic_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_amd64.deb
```

**Note:** You may have to restart your computer after the first command.

<sup>Source:[Liberian Geek](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/05/download-and-install-the-latest-stable-linux-kernel-3-9-4-in-ubuntu/)</sup>

Comment: @MiJyn There you go :)